# Is it possible to add test failures using a junit run listener?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit

I have a simple JUnit `RunListener` that checks whether a test case modifies some shared state (otherwise the next test case may not start expected state).

```
public class SharedStateVerifier extends RunListener {
  @Override
  protected void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
    if (sharedStateHasBeenModified()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("The test case " + description.getDisplayName()
                                 + " has modified the shared state");
    }
  }
}
```

I've added this listener to the maven surefire plugin and it runs against each junit test case in each unit test, as expected.

However I am wondering if I am implementing this correctly. It seems that it will report the first failing test, but if there are more then such tests are not verified, which increases the time to run tests and fix failures. Also, an ugly stack trace is printed after the test summary (to be expected I suppose since the listener is "failing" as far as the maven surefire plugin is concerned.

I could cache each failure and throw a single error that reports all such failures when the `testRunFinished` method is called. But what I really want is to add an error to the test runner itself.

Is this possible?